# Bootstrap 3 buttons vertically align no space

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

How can you align buttons in Bootstrap 3 vertically with no space like this

```
(button 1)
(button 2)
(button 3)
```

Comment: Is this really vertically? Do you want to align or to group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use the [`Vertical variation`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#btn-groups-vertical) example from the docs:

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical">
 ...
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want them HORIZONTAL. The space you're seeing is because, by default, they are `display: inline-block`. `inline-block` gives you a 3 pixel horizontal space between elements. You may want to do `display: block`, and then float the buttons.

Comment: The OP clearly said he wanted to align vertically, plus his example clearly shows vertical buttons. Therefore I think your answer does not address the question...